# Diseño controladores para xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

Hola estoy diseñando en xamarin forms, alguien tiene alguna idea de como podria agregar estos controladores a mi aplicacion?

[image: Controladores de android]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Los iconos son Botones con propiedad image;

```
<Button Text="Has Image" Image="someImage.png" />
```

La barra que tienes con 3 acciones, puede ser un frame con border.

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor:"Green">
<Button source="imagendeX.png "/>
    <Frame CornerRadius="10"  
           OutlineColor="Gray" 
           HeightRequest="100"
            WidthRequest="300"
           >
                <StackLayout>
                  //puedes agregar tus 3 botones o 3 labels para tus acciones expense, income... solo darle un filling sin contorno etc...
                </StackLayout>
    </Frame>

<Button source="imagendePaloma.png "/>

</StackLayout>
```